# When using Two-Weapon Fighting, are your bonuses still added to the offhand attack roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, two-weapon-fighting, attack-roll

I understand how offhand attack works. However, when you roll to hit, would you still add your bonuses to the attack roll?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, you still add any relevant modifiers to the attack roll.

You still use the relevant modifiers for the attack roll (Str/Dex + proficiency bonus + other relevant modifiers) of your bonus-action attack from the [Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) rule. You just don't get to add your ability modifier to the damage roll - if it's positive.

(Note that you do add your ability modifier to the damage roll of the bonus-action attack if your ability modifier is negative, or if some other rule allows it, such as the Two-Weapon Fighting [fighting style](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#FightingStyle-191).)

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by citing the relevant rules. As is, it doesn’t meet our baseline expectations for citing your answers.

Comment: Might want to include that you may add stat modifiers under certain circumstances, such as Two-Weapon Fight Style, one of the traits in Swashbuckler Rogue's tree, as well as the Dual-Wielder feat I believe.

Comment: @HeWhoRulesAsIntended: Only the TWF fighting style adds the ability modifier (Str or Dex, as relevant) to the bonus-action attack. Dual Wielder doesn't do that, though it has other benefits relating to the Two-Weapon Fighting rule. And none of the Swashbuckler rogue's features even directly relate to the Two-Weapon Fighting rule (though it indirectly helps with it by granting the benefit of Disengage against anyone you attack, meaning you don't have to use your bonus action to Disengage).

Comment: @V2Blast Yeah, I was thinking about something else - entirely different. Been a while since I played the game.